# pylint return non zero return status only on error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

When using a `pylint` in CI/CD pipelines, I find myself doing the following to ensure that the full linter output is logged but the pipeline only fails in the case of explicit errors.

```
# Run linter to get full output
pylint dags/ > lint_output.txt

# Run linter to get status code for errors only
pylint -E dags/ > /dev/null
status=$?
```

This is obviously not ideal because I'm having to lint my code twice.

Is there a way to get the same outcome with `pylint` or any other linting tools in Python?

Answer (score 3):

To get the status code for errors only and also to get all the messages, `-e` option of the `pylint` command can be used. For ex.

```
# run pylint, collect all the output and get status based on errors only
pylint -E -e all dags/ > lint_output.txt
status=$?
```